# can we use jfreechart to display an image

Tags: jfreechart

Is there anyway to use jfreechart to load and display an image? say some image.png to display on a JPanel using jfreechart so that we can zoomin, zoomout etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChartPanel class provided in the JFreeChart distribution is the recommmended mechanism for displaying charts in a Swing user interface.

Comment: I would like to display an image not a chart